# Calculate $\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus

When $f(x) = x^2$ calculate $\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ when the range of values for x approach 1 from above and below.

What I have tried:
$$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$$
$$\implies \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)} = x+1$$

Though I think I'm supposed to compute the limit using $f(x+h)$, which in that case I have done this:
$$f(x+h) = \frac{(x+h)^2-1-x^2}{(x-1)h}$$

$$\implies \frac{2xh+h^2-1}{(x-1)h}=\frac{2x+h}{x-1}-\frac{1}{(x-1)h}$$

How might I proceed from here?

Comment: There is a mistake: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ not $(x-1)(x+2).$

Comment: With the "$f(x+h)$ form" you want more than just $f(x+h)$. The denominator is just $h$, which _is_ $x-1$ in the other form. Try thinking about what the algebra _means_ rather than thinking in terms of "forms". You have the numerator wrong too since you did not substitute $x+h$ in the function properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are confused with notations. To calculate the derivative $f'(a)$ by definition, you proceed with either of the following ones:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},\quad \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$

In your example, $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=1$. And the quotients are:
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1,\quad
\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{(1+h)^2-1}{h}=\text{(your exercise)}
$$

Comment: I have a question on $f(a)$ if $a=2$ would I then get $f(a) = 4$ when $f(x) = x^2$? But also, what does it mean 'show show when the range of x approach from above or below'? Do I compute the limit when $\lim_{x \to a}$ and $\lim_{x \to -a}$?

Comment: @emil.limes: Yes. The second one is usually written as $\lim_{x\to a-}$ or $\lim_{x\uparrow a}$.

Comment: Another question If i may; given the left limit, when $\lim_{x \to a}$ do I compute $x+1$ by setting x = a, which is 1 and therefore $1+1=2$? So when computing the limit $\lim_{x \to a-}$ I would get $-1+1 = 0$?

Comment: @emil.limes: you probably need to review what the [one-sided limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) means. When the limit exists, both the left and right sided limit are equal to the limit. In your case, $$\lim_{x\to 1+}(x+1)=\lim_{x\to 1-}(x+1)=\lim_{x\to 1}(x+1)=2$$